# App crashes despite handling Android M GPS permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have been using the android M model for some time now, however recently I manually revoked permissions to location and storage in the  mobile settings  to see whether the app would ask the user again for the permissions at run time. Since then, its been crashing. Please have a look at my code-

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener { 

    String[] perms={"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
    int permsRequestCode = 200;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGeofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        mGeofenceCoordinates = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
//        double string0=prefenceSettings.getString("LatLng0", "34");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        showHelpForFirstLaunch();
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(!isGPSEnabled)
        {
            Utils.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(this);
        }
        Log.i("My activity", "gps is" + isGPSEnabled);

        // getting network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("My activity", "network is" + isNetworkEnabled);

        Criteria crta = new Criteria();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        } else {
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
        }
        /**
         * we have used .setAccuracy as fine for higher SDks than gingerbread .Gingerbread is used as a reference because in apks lower
         * than gingerbread there is very poor geo-fencing, with gingerbread google made it a lot easier for location services to be used for devleopers.
         * it had improved set of tools for Location Services, which included geofencing and substantially improved location discovery.
         */
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);

        /**
         * It request Location updates after every 5 sec or if the user traveled 10m
         */
        Log.i("My activity", "manager is " + locationManager);
        Log.i("My activity", "provider is " + provider);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.i("Api is", "" + mGoogleApiClient);
        }
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        // We want a location update every 10 seconds.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        // We want the location to be as accurate as possible.
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);



    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

        switch(permsRequestCode){

            case 200:

                boolean gpsAccepted = grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for the permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                boolean memoryAccepted = grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        CameraPosition INIT =
                new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .zoom(17.5F)
                        .bearing(300F) // orientation
                        .tilt(50F) // viewing angle
                        .build();
        // use GooggleMap mMap to move camera into position
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(INIT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    }


    public void Add(View view) {

        if (request < 3) {
            String[] arguments = new String[]{String.valueOf(request)};
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("latitude", latitude);
            values.put("true","1");
            values.put("longitude", longitude);
            db.update("Coordinates", values, "id=?", arguments);

            mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            Log.i("The id is", "" + valueindex);
            mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                    .setRequestId("" + valueindex)
                    .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 100)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                            // Required when we use the transition type of GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                    .setLoiteringDelay(50000)
                    .setTransitionTypes(
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());
            mGeofenceStore = new GeofenceStore(this, mGeofences);
            valueindex++;
            request++;




            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("Radius:100m").draggable(false).title(valueindex + "").position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))).showInfoWindow();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum limit exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location mlastlocation;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);


                return;
            }
        }
        mlastlocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        startLocationUpdates();
        if (mlastlocation != null) {
            Log.i("the last location:", "" + mlastlocation);
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Get last location first asshole!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }


    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);

                return;
            }
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

       }
```

Please help me out been searching for days now! My manifest file is fine with all the user permission included

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en Please Check this link you can get an idea what happen when you revoke the Permission.

Answer (score 0):

your error is in this line:

```
   String[] perms={"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
```

change it to

```
   String[] perms={"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"};
```

Comment: hey ankit ,thanks for the swift reply, i was wondering why would that be,since perms indicate a string to add the permissions, i would like to save the coordinates into my sqlite database,hence i used write_external_storage. How could it possibly change the outcome when i change that to access_coarse_location ?

Comment: it still crashes, it doesn't shows the dialog box prompting to grant permissions!